# How is not using Firebase Security Rules a security risk?

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-security

I have a nextjs application and I'm using firebase databse. I have not added security rules as I'm not using authentication.

I'm hosting on vercel and my firebase config is stored in environment variables. I heard that not using firease is a security risk but I don't understand how. Even though the client makes the request, the server API is the one making firebase calls.

How is it that the user can hack my firebase requests and modify my database if I don't use security rules?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how your logic works? Is it like client makes an API call to your APIs hosted somewhere and then that makes Firestore requests further maybe using the Admin SDK? That's secure as long as you check if user is authorized to request the data or no.

Comment: @Dharmaraj The frontend creates a fetch request to the API, the API is hosted on Vercel using NextJS internal node server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client app is not using the provided web or mobile APIs to directly access the database, then security rules are not ever being used.  They only apply to web and mobile access.  Backend access bypasses rules completely.

If you have no direct client access, then security rules are meaningless.  Hackers will have to find some other way to gain unauthorized access to your database other than exploiting a lack of rules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to be clear one more time (sorry for the annoyance), client access refers to using firestore functions in React components/pages directly right (like in useEffect)? 

If I'm only using firestore functions inside API routes and then using axios or fetch to call from client side, I should be relatively safe?

PS: I'm using Next.js' server side rendering too.

Comment: No one can tell you how safe your backend endpoints are, as we can't see any of the code.  If you want people to review your code, you should post that to the code review stack exchange.  Stack Overflow is not suitable for those kinds of questions.

Comment: "Backend access bypasses rules completely" - @DougStevenson am I right in thinking this doesn't apply if you are using the firebase-js-sdk server-side?

"If you are developing a Web or Node.js application that accesses Cloud Firestore on behalf of end users, use the firebase Client SDK"
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore

My understanding is this is saying you could use firebase-js-sdk server-side on a nextjs or remix application to act on the user's behalf, with the added security of any firestore rules you have in place for mobile users?

Comment: I've asked this as a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72239419/using-firebase-security-rules-from-a-web-server